# T-SQL: How to escape slash in context using CONTAINS

Tags: t-sql, contains

I need to find all the instances of the string: "TEXT\00" (nvarchar type field)

```
select * from table
where  contains(TEXT_Extracted, '"TEXT\00"')
```

However, this returns the instances of TEXT fallowed by space ("TEXT ").

I am using T-SQL 2008.

Answer (score -1):

select * from table
where contains(TEXT_Extracted, '"TEXT$\00"') ESCAPE '$'

Comment: CSY, I get the error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ESCAPE'.

Comment: MY bad Joe, I just saw your response on this. Yeah the ESCAPE doesn't work in this scenario. Is your table full-text indexed? It should work with full-text index table.